# Find a Facebook group ID via graph

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Im writing a script to convert facebook user id's in Python. To get a user ID I am simple going to:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/USERNAME
```

Is there any way to access this for groups as well?

I have found other questions like this but none give a definitive answer.

Do I need to use oauth?

I have seen several websites that do what I need such as

http://lookup-id.com/
https://www.wallflux.com/facebook_id/

Comment: you don´t get the username in v2.0 anymore. just saying.

Comment: What? If I go to https://graph.facebook.com/frank I can see his ID?

Comment: ah, i misunderstood. yeah, you get the id if you know the username already. it´s just not possible to get the username by authorizing a user anymore. so you have to know the username, without an app.

Comment: Im just on about converting. Username -> ID or vice versa I can do. I just need the same for groups